# "Delete Conversation..." in Messages.app on Sonoma

Tags: keyboard, messages, sonoma

Has anyone found a way to match a keyboard shortcut to the "`Delete Conversation...`" menu item in Messages.app to delete a conversation?

I had a keyboard shortcut setup, but after upgrading to Sonoma it doesn't seem to work any more. I've gone through the usual procedure of adding it in Keyboard Shortcuts and have tried several combinations (`Command-D`, `Shift-Command-D`, etc.)

If anyone has a trick to make it work please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: I can't check Sonoma, but it used to have a default of Cmd/Backspace [like in Finder & elsewhere]. Are you using a true ellipsis … in your shortcut, or three full stops ...[periods]? This changes by OS, some are fussy, some don't care.

Comment: I did try with an actual ellipsis (Option-;) and it didn't work.

Comment: British keyboard, opt/semicolon - probably the same for US. Others, you'll have to see if you can find it on the Keyboard Viewer. [or cheat & copy/paste from my first comment]

Comment: Yeah that's also the key combination but it didn't work.

Comment: Sorry, not sure then. I don't have Sonoma to check on - these days I never update until about February every year. Stick with the one that works ;)

Comment: Sadly, the machine got upgraded when it was sent out for service to Apple. They did a "revive" on it and didn't even bother to ask the customer if it was okay to upgrade to Sonoma.